# Annoying noise from speakers and earphones

Tags: audio, command

There is a noise coming from the speakers of my notebook since the notebook is turn on (since the physical button is pressed) like this: [noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMfPqeZjc2c)

If I reproduce a sound (like a song or video) the sound can be heard but with that annoying noise.

In Debian I execute this command and the noise is not reproduced anymore:

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

But if I use earphones (3.5mm plug) the noise is still there.

I tried Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows but the noise is always there.

Is there a command to stop the noise for the earphones?

My notebook has this red small subwoofer integrated:

[image: Subwoofer]

```
roberto@lenovo:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
07:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
0a:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: It would help to know the sound devices your notebook has. Add the output of `lspci` (at least the sound related stuff) to your question.

Comment: You are writing "I tried Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows but the noise is always there." - the problem is apparently not related to Linux and we will unlikely find a solution for you here. It seems to be a hardware defect.